# Application of derivatives in geometry

Tags: calculus

> Find the point on the ellipse $16x^2+9y^2=400$ at which the ordinate decreases at the same rate at which the abscissa increases

This is how I attempted it:-

Any point on the ellipse can be take as $\left(\dfrac{20\cos(\theta)}{4}, \dfrac{20\sin(\theta)}{3}\right)$. The rate of increase of abscissa is $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = -\dfrac{20\sin(\theta)}{4}\frac{d(\theta)}{(dt)}$, and the rate of decrease of ordinate is $-\dfrac{dy}{dt} =  -\dfrac{20\cos(\theta)}{3}\frac{d(\theta)}{dt}$. Equating $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, we get a value of $\tan(\theta)$ from which we can find corresponding values of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ from which we can get the corresponding points.

I was confused over whether my approach to the problem is correct ? We usually differentiate the equation of the conic but here I’ve found the parametric coordinates and differentiated them. Do you think this is right ?

Comment: @gimusi yes I just did it . I’m sorry I’d forgotten it earlier . Thanks for your help and thanks for reminding ! :)

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

By implicit differentiation

$$16x^2+9y^2=400\implies 32xdx+18ydy=0\implies\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{16}{9}\frac{x}{y}$$

then set the condition that

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{16}{9}\frac{x}{y}=-1$$

Comment: thank you ! I just wanted to verify whether what I did was correct ? What do you think ?

Comment: @Aditi Yes it seems correct also by your method. You could follow also mine and check if results match.

Comment: According to the solution of the problem , your method is absolutely right ! However I thought about the problem this way and wanted to verify whether it’s correct . Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Aditi Yes absolutely parametric way is a very good approach too. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @Aditi, both methods are equivalent because of the chain rule: $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}.$